# Can you convert two wire 220 (no neutral) to normal 110?

Tags: electrical

We have a water pump way out in the field (500+ long wire run) that is wired for 220 with two wires - no neutral.

It would be very, very convenient to have a power outlet at this site for tools, etc.  However, my electrician said there is no way to add a normal 110 outlet because there is no neutral.

One option is to run a neutral (or maybe run a standalone 110 circuit) in a new conduit, but 500 feet of new underground conduit is a very big job.

Is there any way to (safely, code compliant) get a 110v outlet at this site without running new wires ?

Thank you.

Comment: 500+ feets is a long run. A properly isolated transformer would do the voltage reduction, but your cable should be thick enough to retain the voltage in usable value when you start an electric tool. Get local pro help 1)to check if the job is useful at all for your intended tools and 2)to do the job obeying your local safety and competence requirements.

Comment: I will indeed bring in a professional electrician.  This electrical line has been in use for over 15 years running the 1HP pump @ 220 ... I can't imagine my power tools or my small compressor will load it more than that ...

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use a 220 V to 110 V transformer at the end of the run.

You would need to comply with local electrical regulations<sup>1</sup> to have this installed properly and, in particular, how to "neutralise" one of the 110 V wires and ensure proper earthing of the socket. You may need a better electrician.

---

<sup>1</sup> The location field in your user profile, if filled in, would give a clue as to what regulations would be applicable.

Comment: Thank you.  I see 220v to 110v transformers for sale but they all have wattage ratings - what wattage should I be targeting to approximate a 20 amp 110 household outlet (that would be used for power tools, compressor, etc.)

Comment: @Sparky256: I think you've slipped a decimal place - 20 Amps @ 120 V is 2400 watts by my calculator.

Comment: @PeterBennett. My bad. Thanks for catching that, which means a 50% safety margin equals 3,600 watts. That means about 5.6 KVA. Yikes.

Comment: 'kVA' - not kelvin-volt-amps, says the pedant!